# switchMap not working with string observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, switchmap

switchMap not working with string observable. If I use it inside a function then call the function, it won't work

Below is the stackblitz link to code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-btkudb?file=index.ts

Comment: because on every click you're creating a new subscription without unsubscribing the previous one

Comment: What is the expected result u want

Comment: switchMap should cancel the the previous results and only emit the new results but in this case it starts a new result without canceling the previous one

Comment: Because every time you have a new observable, 

I recommend to you to read that: https://vdsabev.medium.com/the-simple-difference-between-rxjs-switchmap-and-mergemap-397c311552a5

Comment: @martin how can I unsubscribe the previous one in this case ?

Comment: I would recommend that you use RxJS's `fromEvent` instead of adding an event listener manually

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have already imported RxJS `fromEvent` function but instead opted to use `addEventListener()`. I'd say `fromEvent` suits better here since you're trying to pipe in RxJS operators to the event. You could try something like

```js
import { interval, fromEvent, of } from "rxjs";
import { map, tap, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

fromEvent(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector("#app"), "click")
  .pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log("clicked")),
    map(_ => of("test")),              // <-- serves no purpose?
    switchMap(() => interval(1000))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8xstak?file=index.ts).

Working example:

```js
var { interval, fromEvent, of } = rxjs;
var { map, tap, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

fromEvent(document.querySelector("#app"), "click").pipe(
  tap(_ => console.log("clicked")),
  map(_ => of("test")),              // <-- serves no purpose?
  switchMap(() => interval(1000))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">abcd</div>
```

Moreover, while I appreciate the working example in the question, it's always better to write the code in the question instead of only linking to an external website. It ensures question's longevity.

Comment: What should I do If I want to call switchMap over an string, like below code and this function is when user types something in the input ?


function search(query){
  of(query)
    .pipe(
      // restart counter on every click
      switchMap((query) => this.http.getDetails(query))
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
  console.log("clicked");
}

Comment: I have updated the code in the stackblitz for current issue. If we call it inside a function then switchmap does not work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-btkudb?file=index.ts

Comment: You're misunderstanding RxJS observables and also running into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). You can't just slap an `of` to something and expect it to be shared by the piped `switchMap`. For that you'd need to use a multicast like `Subject`. But actual issue presumably doesn't have anything to do with it. Please post the actual requirement with the user input instead of an abstracted code.

Comment: Each call to `foo()` initialized a separate observable with it's own `switchMap` operator. So there are actually 3 simultaneous `of()` with it's own `switchMap`. For the `switchMap` to cancel the old stream, the notifications must be emitted from it's source observable.

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz with updated code and added a detailed explanation of the issue. Please suggest